# how to get backup for sharded mongodb in kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops, google-kubernetes-engine

I was trying to get backup for sharded mongodb backup via so many ways but I couldn't able to do it in some approaches I could able to take backup sucessfully but restoring was not happening and platform.

I use for my kubernetes and other operations are GCP. And I am using bitnami operator for my sharded mongodb and any solutions are there please post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options to take **backup** but as you have not mentioned how and what you tried hard to answer.

You can use the normal **CLI** **mongodump** or **mongoexport** option to take a backup and use it for restart. But based on the size of the data it would be difficult to manage and plan to **restore** it.

If you need to restart to another **Kubernetes** could leverage the Tool **[Velero](https://velero.io/)** and take a Disk snapshot and restore to another **K8s** cluster if running in **GKE**.

Use **third-party** **CLI** or **Operator** to take a backup & upload to **Bucket**.